# Verilog: Is making references to a module's internal registers kosher?

Tags: module, reference, verilog, cpu-registers, internals

I discovered quite accidentally that you can make references to a module's internal registers from outside of that module. This is done by typing the module's instance name then a dot '.' then the register name. This basically bypasses the declared module's port list. I can understand why you can't change the register's value this way, but I see no reason why you can't read its value for use in an assign or some other purpose outside the module in which it resides. I see no difference between this and accessing a module's declared output port. Is doing this kosher? I would appreciate any thoughts on the subject.

Comment: Simple answer: don't.  Such an access makes sense for test benches only in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

Testbenches make heavy use of these kinds of register references for what is called *backdoor* access. The test can bypass the normal method of access through whatever bus protocol has been set up through the module ports. This  can give a tremendous performance boost in simulation.

The problem this causes for synthesis and any other tool that looks your design in hierarchical pieces is the module ports would missing the signals needed to make that access happen, and any logic associated with that access would not be taken into consideration.